# Get all values from YAML file using ruby code

Tags: ruby, yaml

I want t get all the value from this YAML file:

```
Test_server :
  processing_url : "https://test.net/process/"

  xml_files: 
      file: "test1.xml"
      config:
          terminal_name: "test1_gate"
          token: "a86713d51072a01c74b9fbec8c3297be5841546f"
          api_login: "a04d98f30d88b1311c061500fd5a29064f218460"
          api_password: "QUX2NwrZrrx5hQQbb3EmTLXznbUoOpKUY4Pr3iV8"

      file: "test2.xml"
      config:
          terminal_name: "test2_gate"
          token: "8edb910368993e0fb8dea4de37abafd41fbbd697"
          api_login: "1ffd8d50589ee248d00884876b328c2ae268a813"
          api_password: "e4ca6e468332d0ebb47aca4fc0640aa61ebda691"

      file: "test3.xml"
      config:
          terminal_name: "test3_gate"
          token: "abfbed2c74c88bfdd99320511001d850b1915d66"
          api_login: "e2ed5327d59f059ce19d6585eced53873685230e"
          api_password: "AvvYMLgnfJdXSFO7NgVWuAvxRbKcEEI4QT65EGaz"
```

I use this code to get the values:

```
[21] pry(main)> config = YAML.load_file("config/test_config.yml")
=> {"STG_PSP"=>
  {"processing_url"=>"https://test.net/process/",
   "xml_files"=>
    {"file"=>"test3.xml",
     "config"=>
      {"terminal_name"=>"test3_gate",
       "token"=>"abfbed2c74c88bfdd99320511001d850b1915d66",
       "api_login"=>"e2ed5327d59f059ce19d6585eced53873685230e",
       "api_password"=>"AvvYMLgnfJdXSFO7NgVWuAvxRbKcEEI4QT65EGaz"}}}}
[22] pry(main)>
```

Bu as you can see I get always the last value. How I can get all values from the YAML file using Ruby?

Answer (score 1):

What you have is a hash and what you need is a list.

Your yaml file is equivalent to a hash which overwrites values for keys `file` and `config` 3 times.

Your best course of action is to create such list in irb and then save it as yaml.

```
require "yaml"

file1 = {
  file: "test1.xml",
  config: {
      terminal_name: "test1_gate",
      token: "a86713d51072a01c74b9fbec8c3297be5841546f",
      api_login: "a04d98f30d88b1311c061500fd5a29064f218460",
      api_password: "QUX2NwrZrrx5hQQbb3EmTLXznbUoOpKUY4Pr3iV8"
  }
}

file2 = {  
  file: "test2.xml",
  config: {
    terminal_name: "test2_gate",
    token: "8edb910368993e0fb8dea4de37abafd41fbbd697",
    api_login: "1ffd8d50589ee248d00884876b328c2ae268a813",
    api_password: "e4ca6e468332d0ebb47aca4fc0640aa61ebda691"
  }
}

file3 = {
  file: "test3.xml",
  config: {
    terminal_name: "test3_gate",
    token: "abfbed2c74c88bfdd99320511001d850b1915d66",
    api_login: "e2ed5327d59f059ce19d6585eced53873685230e",
    api_password: "AvvYMLgnfJdXSFO7NgVWuAvxRbKcEEI4QT65EGaz"
  }
}

files = [file1, file2, file3]
puts files.to_yaml
```

Output is this:

```
---
- :file: test1.xml
  :config:
    :terminal_name: test1_gate
    :token: a86713d51072a01c74b9fbec8c3297be5841546f
    :api_login: a04d98f30d88b1311c061500fd5a29064f218460
    :api_password: QUX2NwrZrrx5hQQbb3EmTLXznbUoOpKUY4Pr3iV8
- :file: test2.xml
  :config:
    :terminal_name: test2_gate
    :token: 8edb910368993e0fb8dea4de37abafd41fbbd697
    :api_login: 1ffd8d50589ee248d00884876b328c2ae268a813
    :api_password: e4ca6e468332d0ebb47aca4fc0640aa61ebda691
- :file: test3.xml
  :config:
    :terminal_name: test3_gate
    :token: abfbed2c74c88bfdd99320511001d850b1915d66
    :api_login: e2ed5327d59f059ce19d6585eced53873685230e
    :api_password: AvvYMLgnfJdXSFO7NgVWuAvxRbKcEEI4QT65EGaz
```

`-` in beggining of yaml file means this is a list item.
You may have strings as keys, my code is using symbols.

### How to extract all values?

If you want to extract all values from that yaml file, I think easiest approach is to change the yaml file. You need to have a small sample of yaml file which is perfect. Confirm that it's perfect and then just change lines which are not matching.

Lets say that you need to change only `file: "` to `- file: "`
In that case go through it line by line and change lines that match `file: "`

Something like this:

```
# corrects one line in yaml file
# this is just an idea, you need to implement it yourself
def correct_line(line)
  # file_regex - regex to match 'file: "', test using rubular.com
  if line =~ file_regex
    # it's a line that starts with `file: "`
    # change it to start with `- file: "`
    return corrected
  else
    # just return line which is not modified 
    line
  end
end

yaml = YAML.load_file('test.yaml')
original_lines = yaml.split(/\n+/)
corrected_lines = original_lines.map { |line| correct_line(line) }
File.write('/path/to/file', corrected_lines.join("\n"))
```

If you know TDD and rspec, correct_line is perfect candidate to write using TDD.

You could maybe also somehow intercept ruby code which adds new key/value pair to hash and change it to add your entries to list, then save that as yaml. I do not know how to do that.

That may be simpler. I'd google for `how to intercept hash code which adds key value pair in ruby` or something like that. If you can't find it, ask a new question and link to this answer.

Comment: Done. Please accept the answer if you think it answers your question completely.

Comment: Can you please add also ruby code which extracts all values?